# Operator currying: how to convert f[a,b][c,d] to {a+c,b+d}?

Tags: core-language, operators, functional-style

This question is related to [this golfing question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/152092/87058) (but I'm not interested in golfing, only in functional operator composition):

**How can we convert `f[a,b][c,d]` to `{a+c,b+d}` using only [operator forms and function compositions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionCompositionAndOperatorForms.html)?**

So far I've figured out two ways of converting `f[a][b]` to `a+b`:

```
Apply[Curry[Plus]] ~ Operate ~ f[a][b]
(*    a + b    *)

Plus @@ Apply[Curry[List]] ~ Operate ~ f[a][b]
(*    a + b    *)
```

but I'm stumped by the double-argument forms of the first problem, which interferes with [currying](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html). Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both `Operate` and `Curry` don't have access to the full expression, acting mostly on the head. This is why both of them take the depth as an optional argument, to know where to stop, since there is no other way for them to know - their modus operandi is limited to a single interation of evaluation sequence.

What you can do is something like this:

```
curry[expr_, _, 0]:=expr;

curry[head_Symbol, combiner_, n_:2][args___] := 
  curry[head[], combiner, n][args];

curry[head_[prev___], combiner_, n_][args___] := 
  curry[head[prev, combiner[args]], combiner, n-1]
```

which then can be used as:

```
Operate[Apply[curry[List, Plus]], f[a, b][c, d]]

(* {a + b, c + d} *)
```

But in a more complex case like e.g. `f[a, b][c, d][e, f]`, you would have to manually set the depth for both `Operate` and `curry`:

```
Operate[Apply[curry[List, Plus, 3]], f[a, b][c, d][e, f], 2]

(* {a + b, c + d, e + f} *)
```

Not sure how much this takes it away from the operator form paradigm you fancy, but I don't how this could be done much differently, without using some hacks (such as using the `Stack`), which essentially would still serve to get a hold on entire expression rather than just its left-most head.

Comment: A two-argument curry, wow this is really good. Makes me wonder why `Curry` isn't more flexible. Needing to specify the depth, even twice, is of course a hack; but your answer already teaches me a lot. Thank you Leonid!

Comment: To get the order of the summation right, we can do `Plus @@ Operate[Apply[curry[List,List]], f[a,b][c,d]]` to get the desired `{a+c, b+d}`. For larger terms, `Plus @@ Operate[Apply[curry[List,List,4]], f[a,b][c,d][e,f][g,h], 3]` gives `{a+c+e+g, b+d+f+h}`. This usage invites the definition of `listCurry[n_: 2] := curry[List, List, n]` as a curried-argument-to-list-of-lists converter helper: `Plus @@ Operate[Apply[listCurry[]], f[a,b][c,d]]` then gives the desired `{a+c, b+d}`. Alternatively, make default values for the first two arguments of `curry` be `List`.

Comment: Just to give some examples of usage for Leonid's two-argument `curry` operator: `curry[F,G][a,b,c][d,e,f]` gives `F[G[a,b,c], G[d,e,f]]`. The function `F` wraps the whole expression, and each set of arguments is wrapped in `G`. A larger example is `curry[F,G, 4][a,b][c,d][e,f][g,h]` giving `F[G[a,b], G[c,d], G[e,f], G[g,h]]`.

Comment: Leonid, I don't think it's a good idea to auto-detect the depth using `Stack` or similar. What if in the last example of the previous comment I wanted to curry only the first three sets of arguments? `curry[F,G, 3][a,b][c,d][e,f][g,h]` correctly returns `F[G[a,b], G[c,d], G[e,f]][g,h]` and leaves the last argument set `[g,h]` alone. Auto-detection of the depth wouldn't be able to handle this case.

Comment: @Roman Sure, autodetection flies in the face of operator approach, since an operator by itself knows nothing about the depth / order. You can default the combiner to `List`, sure.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my approach built on `RightComposition`, `Through` and `Curry`.

```
myOp=Curry[FixedPoint,{1,2}][Through@*{Head,Apply[List]/*Sow}/*First]/*Reap/*(#[[2,1,;;-3]]&)/*Total
```

```
myOp @ f[a, b][c, d]
(* Out[]= {a + c, b + d} *)
```

#### Where does it come from?

First we define helper operators `pipe` and `branch`:

```
pipe = RightComposition;
branch = Through @* {##} &;
```

`pipe` is just an alias of `RightComposition` for faster typing.

`branch` will be used to distribute functions to arguments. e.g.

```
branch[f, g, h] @ a
(* Out[]= {f[a], g[a], h[a]} *)
branch[f, g, h] @@ {a, b}
(* Out[]= {f[a, b], g[a, b], h[a, b]} *)
branch[F, G, H] @@@ {{a, b}, {c, d, e}}
(* Out[]= {{F[a, b], G[a, b], H[a, b]}, {F[c, d, e], G[c, d, e], H[c, d, e]}} *)
```

Now we can define our desired operator as following:

```
myOp = pipe[
  branch[Head, pipe[Apply@List, Sow]] /* First // Curry[FixedPoint, {1, 2}]
  , Reap, #[[2, 1, ;; -3]] &, Total
  ]
(* Out[]= Curry[FixedPoint, {1, 2}][(Through@*{Head, Apply[List] /* Sow}) /* 
   First] /* Reap /* (#1[[2, 1, 1 ;; -3]] &) /* Total *)
```

Generate a lengthy example expression:

```
testExpr = 5 // pipe[
   Range
   , Map@branch[x, y]
   , Fold[Apply, F, #] &
   ]
(* Out[]= F[x[1], y[1]][x[2], y[2]][x[3], y[3]][x[4], y[4]][x[5], y[5]] *)
```

Using `myOp` on `testExpr` gives desired result:

```
testExpr // myOp
(* Out[]= {x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5],  y[1] + y[2] + y[3] + y[4] + y[5]} *)
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks @Silvia!

Comment: @Roman Thanks for the kind words. My real intention here is promoting my `branch` & `pipe` style. :D

Answer (score 2):

One more approach, learned a bunch tackling this. Basically grab the arguments of the functions and `Sow`-ing them as lists, and then grabbing the `Head` (leaving the previous arguments behind) and repeating until having walked through all of the `Head` using `NestWhile`

Define

```
ff = (Sow[List @@ #]; Head[#]) &
```

and

```
funk[t_] := Plus @@ Last@Last@Reap@NestWhile[ff, t, Length[#] > 0 &];
```

Test

```
t = f[a, b][c, d][j, k][r, s];
funk@t
(*  {a + c + j + r, b + d + k + s}  *)
```

Again

```
tt = gg[a, b, c][d, e, g][q, r, s]
funk@tt

(* {a + d + q, b + e + r, c + g + s} *)
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks, I learned a lot here too! I've modified your code a bit: `funk = Plus @@ Reap[FixedPoint[(Sow[List @@ #]; Head[#]) &, #]][[2, 1, ;; -3]] &`. Not sure about the best stopping criterion yet. Cheers!

Comment: I started with `FixedPoint` but struggled with capturing just the data I wanted. Nice rewrite...cleaner function!

Answer (score 2):

Not really what you're looking for, but another cute way to do this using the fact that a pure-function captures its `Head`. We use an empty function call as a terminator for our threading process.

```
threader =
  If[Length[{##}] > 0, 
    Insert[#0, {##}, {1, 3, 2, -1}],
    MapThread[Plus, {}]
    ] &;

threader[a, b][c, d][e, f][g, h][]

{a + c + e + g, b + d + f + h}
```

Note too that we could generalize this like:

```
threadable[f_]:=
  If[Length[{##}] > 0, 
    Insert[#0, {##}, {1, 3, 2, -1}],
    MapThread[f, {}]
    ] &;

threadable[Plus][a, b][c, d][e, f][g, h][]

{a + c + e + g, b + d + f + h}
```

Comment: Cool, that's a nifty trick! Thanks.